# Find The Deepest Node Of A Binary Tree. If Multiple Nodes Are At The Deepest Level, Then Return The Rightmost Node. (the answer is in the desc)

Tags: java, node.js

Recently I've been working on personal projects and this error always came up. Async isn't valid unless there's an await function I don't know man, and this is the code that gave me an error with that, however. My code doesn't have an async function, so it was so annoying attempting to remove that. And I did remove it, check the answers for more information and if you want to copy the code.

```
// Java program to find value of the deepest node
// in a given binary tree
class GFG
{
 
    // A tree node
    static class Node
    {
 
        int dataa;
        Node left, right;
 
        Node(int key)
        {
            data = key;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
    static int maxLevel = -1;
    static int res = -1;
 
    // maxLevel : keeps track of maximum level seen so far.
    // res : Value of deepest node so far.
    // level : Level of root
    static void find(Node root, int level)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            find(root.left, ++level);
 
            // Update level and resue
            if (level > maxLevel)
            {
                res = root.data;
                maxLevel = level;
            }
 
            find(root.right, level);
        }
    }
 
    // Returns value of deepest node
    static int deepestNode(Node root)
    {
        // Initialze result and max level
        /* int res = -1;
        int maxLevel = -1; */
 
        // Updates value "res" and "maxLevel"
        // Note that res and maxLen are passed
        // by reference.
        find(root, 0);
        return res;
    }
 
    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
 
        Node root = new Node(1);
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(3);
        root.left.left = new Node(4);
        root.right.left = new Node(5);
        root.right.right = new Node(6);
        root.right.left.right = new Node(7);
        root.right.right.right = new Node(8);
        root.right.left.right.left = new Node(9);
        System.out.println(deepestNode(root));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the reason it was giving me that stupid error was this:

```
int dataa;
```

And I kept on calling int dataa; as int data, and because of that, Node thought it was funny to literally give me and possibly all of you with the same problem the same incorrect exception handling. And some other stuff as well in the code was giving out the wrong exception handling, anyway, just copy this code if you need it. However, that was just a spelling error, that wasn't the only problem, I fixed that int dataa; and I got more problems with the same exception handling trashy crap. (ps. I tried putting the errors and the solution to the problem but it was too much characters and I had to shorten it. just copy the code if you need it!)

```
// Java program to find value of the deepest node
// in a given binary tree
class GFG
{

    // A tree node
    static class Node
    {

        int data;
        Node left, right;

        Node(int key)
        {
            data = key;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
    static int maxLevel = -1;
    static int res = -1;

    // maxLevel : keeps track of maximum level seen so far.
    // res : Value of deepest node so far.
    // level : Level of root
    static void find(Node root, int level)
    {
        if (root != null)
        {
            find(root.left, ++level);

            // Update level and reuse
            if (level > maxLevel)
            {
                res = root.data;
                maxLevel = level;
            }

            find(root.right, level);
        }
    }

    // Returns value of deepest node
    static int deepestNode(Node root)
    {
        // Initialze result and max level
        /* int res = -1;
        int maxLevel = -1; */

        // Updates value "res" and "maxLevel"
        // Note that res and maxLen are passed
        // by reference.
        find(root, 0);
        return res;
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Node root = new Node(1);
        root.left = new Node(2);
        root.right = new Node(3);
        root.left.left = new Node(4);
        root.right.left = new Node(5);
        root.right.right = new Node(6);
        root.right.left.right = new Node(7);
        root.right.right.right = new Node(8);
        root.right.left.right.left = new Node(9);
        System.out.println(deepestNode(root));
    }
}
```

This is why Node is the best for programming as it makes your life hell for multiple hours! Upvote this question so other people don't